# Is there any way to hide a div from source code at runtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there any way to hide a div from source code at **runtime**

Using jquery, javascript or any other method.

Eg:

```
<div id="abc">
This will not be displayed on source as well as in page
</div>
```

By using jQuery `remove()` or `hide()` - the item is hidden from front end.
But i need to remove it from source...

I'm using drupal render method.

Comment: then, why do you include the div? xD

Comment: it will automatically displayed from render method in drupal...

Comment: You're likely attacking the problem from the wrong angle. Since you're using Drupal, look into the hooks system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to hide DOM elements in browser. You can only remove them using `.remove()` or hide with `.hide()` when rendered. But if DOM exist in code then you can not hide it in view source code component.

Comment: see the first part. it is not possible to hide dom in source code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution

In your body tag add onload event

```
<body onload='removeDiv()'>
    <div id='abc'>
         This will not displayed in source code as well as in web page.
    </div>
<body>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function removeDiv(){
        var div = document.getElementById('abc');
        div.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This will still definitely be displayed in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $('.abc').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the .hide() and .remove() doesn't work for you. You can try this.
Make a parent div and set the html part empty

```
  <div id="def">
     <div id="abc">
        This will not be displayed on source as well as in page
     </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#def").html('');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using drupal the write a php if condition to hide the content of the div, example

```
<?php if(1){ ?>
<div id="abc">
This will not be displayed on source as well as in page
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: i got the div from calling a function, i need to change it on front end, editing the function may reflect functionalities in other areas.